# How to use Spring's BackendIdConverter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I have an entity named *VendorProductMapping* with embedded primary key. Hence I want to use BackendIdConverter to convert the embedded primary key to string and vice-versa.
I followed a few posts on stackoverflow and learnt that I need to use BackendIdConverter.
I created the following class:

```
public class VendorProductMappingIdConverter implements BackendIdConverter {

@Override
public Serializable fromRequestId(String id, Class<?> entityType) {
    --
}

@Override
public String toRequestId(Serializable source, Class<?> entityType) {
    --
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
    --
}
```

}

The very first line gives me an error saying

> Cannot resolve symbol 'BackendIdConverter'

Do I explicitly need to create a BackendIdConverter interface ?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>UI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**EDIT:**
Now that I've written a converter class, how do I use this ?
I need to send the primary key of *VendorProductMapping* class (i.e, *VendorProductMappingPk*) may be in an anchor tag. The error I see is

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.UI.entity.VendorProductMappingPk'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.UI.entity.VendorProductMappingPk': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: Can you please add your `pom.xml`? Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoDias Thanks. I just added. Please check

Answer (score 0):

`BackendIdConverter` is part of Spring Boot Data REST, so try adding the following dependency. However, I am not sure this is what you need for your case.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I would say you need a JPA converter to achieve this:

```java
@Converter
public class PersonNameConverter implements AttributeConverter<YourEmbeddedPrimaryKeyClass, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(YourEmbeddedPrimaryKeyClass id) {
        // your conversion to String logic
    }

    @Override
    public YourEmbeddedPrimaryKeyClass convertToEntityAttribute(String id) {
        // your conversion to YourEmbeddedPrimaryKeyClass logic
    }
}
```

Then you can configure this converter in your model:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(PK.class)
public class YourClass {
  @Id
  private YourEmbeddedPrimaryKeyClass id;
  ...
}

public class PK implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "MY_ID_FIELD")
  @Convert(converter = IdConverter.class)
  private YourEmbeddedPrimaryKeyClass id;
}
```

You can check additional details at https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters.

Comment: this works, the error is gone, thanks. Also, please check the newly added edit to my question. Thanks.

Comment: As I suspected, you need something else, not `BackendIdConverter`. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: If it helped you you might upvote my answer and even accept it as the answer so that others can understand easily how to solve exactly the same issue.